# Capybara/Selenium Webdriver + DataTables not playing nicely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a page, that once loaded, calls DataTables on two different tables. However, upon page load, the second table is erroring out. Here's the error:

`DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

What's annoying, is that if I put a `debugger` right after the page load in Capybara, I can click the error to close it, then manually reload the data in the DataTable with a button I have on the page, and it works fine. Also strange, is that the first DataTable on the page loads fine (and it has DataTable() called on it PRIOR to the one that's breaking). I thought maybe it was an issue on the server side that returns the info to populate the table with, but it turns out it's never hitting the server (until I hit the reload button). If I load another page with only one DataTable on it, it shows the same error. Which is strange, since the first table on the page with two tables loads, but the one table on the page with one table breaks by itself.

Has anyone seen anything like this? I would post my Capybara code, but it's literally just visiting the page that causes the issue, nothing fancy at all.

I thought at first it was an issue with JS being called too quickly or something, but the one page with one table breaking, and only the SECOND table breaking on the other page, is a bit strange. Again, it's never hitting the server (which it should be) on page load, so it's nothing on the back-end. Not sure where to start with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more debugging, I realized that there was a subtle (didn't show in the logs, since server logs weren't being printed in my test environment) 414 error happening. Capybara apparently prevents long GET requests (though major browsers now support them), so I posted an issue here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1467

I'd rather not use a POST for an index route :)

Comment: Excellent! I had the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

From versions 2.7.0 onwards, Capybara supports server configuration natively.

Just add `gem 'puma'` to your `Gemfile` and the following line to `rails_helper.rb` :

`Capybara.server = :puma`

This will solve 414 (Request-URI Too Large) errors and Datatables will work properly with Capybara.